# How to properly compile programs in assembly language on arm?

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, arm

I want to run the assembly code on ubuntu 20.04 arm64, so I do the following:

```
    .text
.global _start
_start:
    mov r0, #1
    ldr r1, =message
    ldr r2, =len
    mov r7, #4
    swi 0

    mov r7, #1
    swi 0

.data
message:
    .asciz "hello world\n"
len = .-message
```

I'm trying to run this program, it's called `hello.s`

Next, I tried to convert the source file via `as`, but it didn't work, so I took advantage of this

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-as hello.s -o hello.o
```

Now I'm trying to get an executable file

```
ld hello.o -o hello
```

and I get this error

```
ld: hello.o: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
```

Can someone help?

P.S
I also tried `nasm -f elf hello.asm`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN0lf.png)

Comment: If you use `arm-linux-gnueabihf-as` then try `arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld` to link. What was the error with plain `as`? "didn't work" is not a good problem description.

Comment: @Jester, ok, `arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld hello.o` get me a.out and  `arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld -s -o hello hello.o` get me hello, but `./hello` return me `./hello: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Jester, `as hello.asm -o hello.o` return

`hello.asm: Assembler messages:
hello.asm:4: Error: operand 1 must be an integer register -- 'mov r0,#1'
hello.asm:5: Error: operand 1 must be an integer register -- 'ldr r1,=message'
hello.asm:6: Error: operand 1 must be an integer register -- 'ldr r2,=len'
hello.asm:7: Error: operand 1 must be an integer register -- 'mov r7,#4'
hello.asm:8: Error: unknown mnemonic 'swi' -- 'swi 0'
hello.asm:10: Error: operand 1 must be an integer register -- 'mov r7,#1'
hello.asm:11: Error: unknown mnemonic 'swi' -- 'swi 0'`

Comment: Oh, you are trying to write 32 bit code on a 64 bit system. Looks like your machine is not set up to allow that.

Comment: @Jester, how did you understand this?

Comment: Your code is clearly 32 bit. When you use the 32 bit toolchain you do get a binary output, but you can't run it. When you try to assemble using the native 64 bit assembler it barfs because it doesn't like 32 bit code.

Comment: arm-whatever-whatever is for 32 bit arm binaries.  arm64, or aarch64 is a completely incompatible instruction set, as in compatible as arm to x86, to mips.  so the gnu folks have a separate target aarch64-whatever-whatever.   that is how we know you are building a 32 bit binary or aarch32...the stock linker ld is for aarch64 and doesnt recognize aarch32 objects just like an x86 or mips or riscv etc ld does not recognize arm.

Comment: depending on the platform you are running you can probably get a 32 bit ubuntu and within that you can learn some arm (32 bit) instruction set basics.  Otherwise with what you appear to have here you should instead learn the aarch64.  This doesnt mean it is impossible to run 32 bit arm programs on 64 bit systems.  how the operating system works to do that and what you need to do I dont know.  the armv8 based cores have armv7 compatbility built in (aarch32 and aarc64 are supported in some way by the same chip).

Comment: @Shrek1995: In 32-bit ARM assembly, `r0` *is* an integer register.  In 64-bit AArch64 assembly, it's not.  The integer registers are `w0..31` and `x0..31`.  So an error message like `operand 1 must be an integer register` for `mov r0,#1` is a clear sign that you're not assembling for ARM32.  Also, NASM is an x86 assembler only, so that definitely won't work on this source.

Comment: Does ARM64 GCC support `gcc -m32 -nostdlib -static hello.S` to assemble + link a 32-bit binary?  If no, then use `arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld` to link your `arm-linux-gnueabihf-as` output; that's why you installed a cross toolchain after all.

Comment: Many 64-bit ARM CPUs do not support running 32-bit code. These are mostly some of the newest designs by ARM ltd or third-party designs such as ThunderX

Comment: The term "compile" implies a step of translation. Converting assembler mnemonic opcodes to actual machine instructions is simply called "assembling".

Comment: @PeterCordes both `x31` or `w31` are not available. :-)